# Implementing a Windows Credential Provider

Tags: windows, rust, com, windows-credential-provider, windows-rs

I recently discovered the [windows-rs](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs) framework and have been looking to build a [Windows Credential Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/credential-providers-in-windows) in Rust by implementing their [ICredentialProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nn-credentialprovider-icredentialprovider) COM interface.

I've been working on a proof-of-concept implementation using the information put together under one of the [existing issues](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/issues/2304), but I'm not sure how to actually expose the compiled rust as a proper DLL to then register with the windows system.

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;

use windows::{
    core::implement,
    Win32::UI::Shell::{ICredentialProvider, ICredentialProvider_Impl},
};

fn main() -> windows::core::Result<()> {
    #[implement(ICredentialProvider)]
    struct Provider {
        mutable_state: RefCell<u32>,
    }

    impl Provider {
        fn new() -> Self {
           Self {
               mutable_state: RefCell::new(0),
           }
       }
    }

    impl ICredentialProvider_Impl for Provider {
        fn Advise(
            &self,
            pcpe: &core::option::Option<windows::Win32::UI::Shell::ICredentialProviderEvents>,
            upadvisecontext: usize,
        ) -> windows::core::Result<()> {
           *self.mutable_state.borrow_mut() = 42;
            todo!();
        }

        fn GetCredentialAt(
            &self,
            dwindex: u32,
        ) -> windows::core::Result<windows::Win32::UI::Shell::ICredentialProviderCredential>
        {
            todo!();
        }

        fn GetCredentialCount(
            &self,
            pdwcount: *mut u32,
            pdwdefault: *mut u32,
            pbautologonwithdefault: *mut windows::Win32::Foundation::BOOL,
        ) -> windows::core::Result<()> {
            todo!();
        }

        fn GetFieldDescriptorAt(
            &self,
            dwindex: u32,
        ) -> windows::core::Result<
            *mut windows::Win32::UI::Shell::CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_FIELD_DESCRIPTOR,
        > {
            todo!();
        }

        fn GetFieldDescriptorCount(&self) -> windows::core::Result<u32> {
            todo!();
        }

        fn SetSerialization(
            &self,
            pcpcs: *const windows::Win32::UI::Shell::CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION,
        ) -> windows::core::Result<()> {
            todo!();
        }

        fn SetUsageScenario(
            &self,
            cpus: windows::Win32::UI::Shell::CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO,
            dwflags: u32,
        ) -> windows::core::Result<()> {
            todo!();
        }

        fn UnAdvise(&self) -> windows::core::Result<()> {
            todo!();
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

I compiled a [Sample Credential Provider](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/master/security/credentialproviders/samplecredentialprovider) written in C++, supplied by Windows in their SDK, and used a tool to view the [exported functions available in the generated DLL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg7ex.png)

There have been [similar efforts](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/tree/master/crates/tests/component) in the windows-rs community to expose rust for WinRT but this COM interface needed for the Credential Provider is different enough I don't really know where to begin.

Are there any rust tricks to generate a similar DLL that can expose my interface and make it available to windows? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just so that I understand the issue, what you're having difficulty with is exporting the functions that make your code a COM server, is that correct?

Comment: @IInspectable that's correct yeah.

I've been trying to reference how the [C++ project](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/blob/master/security/credentialproviders/helpers/Dll.cpp) does this in comparison to how [another windows-rs project](https://github.com/Alovchin91/winrt-component-rs/tree/main/WinRTComponent/src) but so far I'm not sure how to implement it since the circumstances are so different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A credential provider needs to be implemented as a [COM server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/com-clients-and-servers). A COM server is a PE image (EXE or DLL) that provides the following exports:

- [`DllGetClassObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-dllgetclassobject)
- [`DllCanUnloadNow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-dllcanunloadnow)<sup>1</sup>

`DllGetClassObject` is where the magic happens: It checks to see if the requested class (identified by `rclsid`) is implemented by the module, and subsequently returns a pointer to the requested interface `riid` (commonly an [`IClassFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nn-unknwn-iclassfactory) or [`IClassFactory2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ocidl/nn-ocidl-iclassfactory2) interface). Once a client (the operating system, in case of a credential provider) received a class factory, it can use it to [instantiate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iclassfactory-createinstance) objects that implement interfaces such as the `ICredentialProvider` interface.

The key point here is that those two exports are all that's required for a module to be a COM server, that can expose arbitrary interfaces<sup>2</sup>.

That covers the systemic invariants. Moving into Rust the following issues need to be addressed:

### Problem statement

1. Create a crate that produces a DLL
2. Instruct the linker to export symbols by a given name
3. Implement the interfaces
4. Implement the exported functions

### Solution

1. First up, let's create a *library* crate. The following will do:

   ```
   cargo new --lib cp_demo
   ```

   Add this to *Cargo.toml* (removing anything beyond the `[package]` table):

   ```ini
   [lib]
   crate-type = ["cdylib"]
   ```

   That addresses the first issue by having the crate produce a DLL. Running `cargo build` will produce *cp_demo.dll* inside *targets/debug* (assuming default settings). Mind you, this isn't making forward progress just yet. It merely creates a DLL that doesn't export anything (evidenced by running `dumpbin /EXPORTS targets\debug\cp_demo.dll`). It merely removes the obligation to have a `fn main()`.
2. Having an "empty" DLL in place, we'll want to expose functionality to the outside world. The mechanics are very similar to the referenced [resources](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/tree/master/crates/tests/component), requiring a combination of an [`extern "system"`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/external-blocks.html) block as well as the [`no_mangle`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/abi.html#the-no_mangle-attribute) attribute, so that the exports can be discovered by the system by name.

   The former designates the calling convention, the contract between callers (the system) and callees (the implementation), formalizing how arguments are passed and who is responsible for (stack) cleanup on return. The latter instructs the linker to keep the exported symbols undecorated, so that the system can discover them by calling `GetProcAddress(hmod, "DllGetClassObject")`, for example.

   Dumping the following into *src/lib.rs*

   ```rust
   use std::{ffi, ptr};

   use windows::{
       core::{GUID, HRESULT},
       Win32::Foundation::{CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE, E_POINTER, S_OK},
   };

   #[no_mangle]
   extern "system" fn DllGetClassObject(
       _rclsid: *const GUID,
       _riid: *const GUID,
       ppv: *mut *mut ffi::c_void,
   ) -> HRESULT {
       // Implement basic COM contract
       if ppv.is_null() {
           E_POINTER
       } else {
           unsafe { *ppv = ptr::null_mut() };
           CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE
       }
   }

   #[no_mangle]
   extern "system" fn DllCanUnloadNow() -> HRESULT {
       // It's always safe to unload this module
       S_OK
   }
   ```

   and updating *Cargo.toml* to include

   ```ini
   [dependencies.windows]
   version = "0.44.0"
   features = [
       "Win32_Foundation",
   ]
   ```

   complies into a credential provider skeleton DLL. Running `dumpbin /EXPORTS targets\debug\cp_demo.dll` again produces output that includes

   ```
       ordinal hint RVA      name

             1    0 00001080 DllCanUnloadNow = DllCanUnloadNow
             2    1 00001000 DllGetClassObject = DllGetClassObject
   ```

   Sweet! Now we have a credential provider that doesn't provide anything (and certainly not credentials). But it *looks* like a potential credential provider to the system already, that can be registered using the following .reg script (make sure to use a fresh GUID; this one won't be "globally unique" anymore by the time you're reading this).

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\{DED30376-B312-4168-B2D3-2D0B3EADE513}]
   @="cp_demo"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{DED30376-B312-4168-B2D3-2D0B3EADE513}]
   @="cp_demo"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{DED30376-B312-4168-B2D3-2D0B3EADE513}\InprocServer32]
   @="cp_demo.dll"
   "ThreadingModel"="Apartment"
   ```
3. The interface implementations follow the pattern you've already used in the question: Declare a custom type to hold local state (if any), apply the `#[implement]` attribute, and supply an implementation for the generated trait named `<interface>_Impl`.

   For the `ICredentialProvider` interface<sup>3</sup> this would roughly look like what is in the question. The only exception being that the following snippet replaces the `todo!()`'s with returning error codes, as it isn't legal for panics to cross the ABI<sup>4</sup>.

   ```rust
   #[implement(ICredentialProvider)]
   struct Provider {
       _mutable_state: cell::RefCell<u32>,
   }

   impl Provider {
       fn new() -> Self {
           Self {
               _mutable_state: cell::RefCell::new(0),
           }
       }
   }

   impl ICredentialProvider_Impl for Provider {
       fn SetUsageScenario(
           &self,
           _cpus: CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO,
           _dwflags: u32,
       ) -> Result<()> {
            Err(E_NOTIMPL.into())
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```

   This isn't doing anything useful, other than failing gracefully in case the system manages to instantiate this implementation. To do this it needs an `IClassFactory` implementation that does:

   ```rust
   #[implement(IClassFactory)]
   struct ProviderFactory;

   impl IClassFactory_Impl for ProviderFactory {
       fn CreateInstance(
           &self,
           punkouter: &core::option::Option<windows::core::IUnknown>,
           riid: *const windows::core::GUID,
           ppvobject: *mut *mut core::ffi::c_void,
       ) -> windows::core::Result<()> {
           // Validate arguments
           if ppvobject.is_null() {
               return Err(E_POINTER.into());
           }
           unsafe { *ppvobject = ptr::null_mut() };
           if riid.is_null() {
               return Err(E_INVALIDARG.into());
           }
           let riid = unsafe { *riid };
           if punkouter.is_some() {
               return Err(CLASS_E_NOAGGREGATION.into());
           }

           // We're only handling requests for `IID_ICredentialProvider`
           if riid != ICredentialProvider::IID {
               return Err(E_NOINTERFACE.into());
           }

           // Construct credential provider and return it as an `ICredentialProvider`
           // interface
           let provider: ICredentialProvider = Provider::new().into();
           unsafe { *ppvobject = mem::transmute(provider) };
           Ok(())
       }

       fn LockServer(&self, _flock: windows::Win32::Foundation::BOOL) -> windows::core::Result<()> {
           Err(E_NOTIMPL.into())
       }
   }
   ```

   This represents a fully functional class factory for an `ICredentialProvider` interface implemented by `Provider`. The better part of `CreateInstance()` consists of argument validation as mandated by the contract for [`IClassFactory::CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iclassfactory-createinstance). The actual magic happens here:

   ```rust
   let provider: ICredentialProvider = Provider::new().into();
   ```

   This is doing a lot! `Provider::new()` is the obvious part: It instantiates a new `Provider` object. Not nearly as obvious is what the `into()` part does. It exercises the following `From` trait implementation that is ultimately generated by the `#[implement]` macro ([`cargo-expand`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-expand) is an indispensable tool for uncovering those hidden details):

   ```rust
   impl ::core::convert::From<Provider> for ICredentialProvider {
       fn from(this: Provider) -> Self {
           let this = Provider_Impl::new(this);
           let mut this = ::core::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(::std::boxed::Box::new(this));
           let vtable_ptr = &this.vtables.0;
           unsafe { ::core::mem::transmute(vtable_ptr) }
       }
   }
   ```

   It takes a `Provider` instance, *moves* it into a (generated) `Provider_Impl`, then moves that into heap storage (`Box::new()`), wraps everything behind a `ManuallyDrop`, and finally transmutes the object pointer into the respective interface pointer.

   Every bit of this is of crucial importance: Moving the `Provider` instance into heap memory makes sure that it remains valid across stack unwinding as part of function return, wrapping the `Box` inside a `ManuallyDrop` inhibits running the `Drop` implementation as the object falls out of scope (which would otherwise decrement the reference count to 0, destroying the object along the way), and returning an interface pointer allows the system to call into an unknown implementation through a known interface.

   A corollary of the latter is that object cleanup is at the discretion of the implementation: When the reference count drops to 0, as clients call through `Release()`, it is the concrete implementation that frees resources (`Provider_Impl::Release()` specifically), irrespective of who the caller happens to be. `Provider_Impl` makes sure to match the allocation strategy used by the `From` trait implementation, so we don't have to worry about this detail.

   A note on the `LockServer` implementation: It retuns `E_NOTIMPL`, mostly because I'm not confident to have understood it's purpose. This doesn't appear to have had any adverse effect while debugging, so I'm leaving it for now (more on this later).
4. With all that in place, we are in a good position to socialize: We have an `ICredentialProvider` implementation (`Provider`), that'll faithfully respond with `E_NOTIMPL` on *every* request, and an `IClassFactory` implementation (`ProviderFactory`), that'll dutifully procure as many of the aforementioned rascals as requested. What's missing in becoming [BFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_friends_forever) with the OS is to allow it to partake in our parenthood.

   - Detour on credential provider lookup and instantiation: Whenever the system needs to discover credential providers, it enumerates all [values](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090204-00/?p=19263) under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\` key in the registry. Each value's data names a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (generally referred to as a "GUID" in Windows programming) that identifies a credential provider implementation.

     With a GUID identifying a COM interface implementation, what follows is rather generic COM infrastructure business. This applies to all of COM, not just credential providers. The (approximately accurate) algorithm is this:

     1. Look up the GUID under the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\` key. Its [`InprocServer32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/inprocserver32)'s data contains the (fully qualified) path to the implementing module.
     2. [Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexw) the module and [request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress) an export called `DllGetClassObject` (the literal name is part of the contract, hence the `#[no_mangle]` attribute).
     3. [Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-dllgetclassobject) a class factory capable of instantiating a COM object identified by the given GUID (take note that GUID's are used to identify both COM interfaces as well as interface implementations, or "COM objects"; the former is generally spelled `IID` as in "interface ID", whereas the latter is referred to as `CLSID` as in "class ID").
     4. Have the class factory [create an instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iclassfactory-createinstance).

   That out of the way, it should be apparent why the .reg script above writes to two different keys, and also what's required to nudge the system into acknowledging this creation of our own: Step `3.` above is the missing link, so let's fill that in:

   ```rust
   #[no_mangle]
   extern "system" fn DllGetClassObject(
       rclsid: *const GUID,
       riid: *const GUID,
       ppv: *mut *mut ffi::c_void,
   ) -> HRESULT {
       // The "class ID" this credential provider is identified by. This value needs to
       // match the value used when registering the credential provider (see the .reg
       // script above)
       const CLSID_CP_DEMO: GUID = GUID::from_u128(0xDED30376_B312_4168_B2D3_2D0B3EADE513);

       // Validate arguments
       if ppv.is_null() {
           return E_POINTER;
       }
       unsafe { *ppv = ptr::null_mut() };
       if rclsid.is_null() || riid.is_null() {
           return E_INVALIDARG;
       }

       let rclsid = unsafe { *rclsid };
       let riid = unsafe { *riid };
       // The following isn't strictly correct; a client *could* request an interface other
       // than `IClassFactory::IID`, which this implementation is simply failing.
       // This is safe, even if overly restrictive
       if rclsid != CLSID_CP_DEMO || riid != IClassFactory::IID {
           return CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE;
       }

       // Construct the factory object and return its `IClassFactory` interface
       let factory: IClassFactory = ProviderFactory.into();
       unsafe { *ppv = mem::transmute(factory) };
       S_OK
   }

   #[no_mangle]
   extern "system" fn DllCanUnloadNow() -> HRESULT {
       // Since we aren't tracking module references (yet), it's never safe to unload this
       // module
       S_FALSE
   }
   ```

   This is following a familiar pattern: Most of `DllGetClassObject()` is argument validation, with `let factory: IClassFactory = ProviderFactory.into();` doing the actual work.

   The only difference here being that `ProviderFactory` is stateless (a "unit struct" in Rust parlance). It doesn't carry any information beyond it being a type. Which doesn't immediately appear to be useful, though it does allow us to implement traits on it (such as [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html)). With `ProviderFactory` a [unit struct expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/struct-expr.html#unit-struct-expression) we can call `into()` on it, kicking off the same machinery as described above, leaving use with a manually managed COM object living in heap memory so that we can return a pointer to it (`*ppv = mem::transmute(factory)`).

   Note that the `DllCanUnloadNow` implementation changed from returning `S_OK` to `S_FALSE`. This isn't wrong as such, but it's also not what I'd like to do<sup>1</sup>. To address this we would need to record all references into this module, incrementing the reference count on every object creation, and decrementing it whenever objects implemented by this module get destroyed. I'm not entirely sure how to do that yet.

The final step closes the loop. With the above we can compile a credential provider DLL, allow the system to discover it and load the module, request a class factory from it, and have it create a credential provider. The credential provider doesn't do anything just yet; fleshing out the `ICredentialProvider` skeleton with functionality is for another update.

### Debugging

For debugging I've set up a VM using [Hyper-V](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/about/). The choice was a matter of convenience, as Hyper-V comes as an optional system component, with OS installations available for immediate download (I'm using *"Windows 10 MSIX packaging environment"* as the smallest option). Any other VM solution or OS installation should work the same.

- *TBD:* VM and debugger setup
- While possible to attach a debugger to the Windows logon screen, it's much more convenient to run everything under the local user's account. To that end I'd implemented a tiny test program (`cp_test`) that exercises the credential provider by way of the [`CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/nf-wincred-creduipromptforwindowscredentialsw) API call.

  This program can be launched from a debugger, with all the credential provider business running in-process. There's no need to attach a debugger to an external process, and everything just works as you'd expect.

  This is the test application:

  *Cargo.toml*

  ```ini
  [package]
  name = "cp_test"
  version = "0.0.0"
  edition = "2021"

  [dependencies.windows]
  version = "0.44.0"
  features = [
      "Win32_Foundation",
      "Win32_Graphics_Gdi",
      "Win32_Security_Credentials",
  ]
  ```

  *src/main.rs*

  ```rust
  use std::{mem, ptr};

  use windows::{
      w,
      Win32::{
          Foundation::BOOL,
          Security::Credentials::{
              CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW, CREDUIWIN_CHECKBOX, CREDUI_INFOW,
          },
      },
  };

  fn main() {
      let ui_info = CREDUI_INFOW {
          cbSize: mem::size_of::<CREDUI_INFOW>() as _,
          pszMessageText: w!("Enter credentials"),
          pszCaptionText: w!("Testing custom credential provider"),
          ..Default::default()
      };
      let mut auth_package = 0;
      let mut auth_buffer = ptr::null_mut();
      let mut auth_buffer_size = 0;
      let mut save = BOOL::default();
      let _ = unsafe {
          CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW(
              Some(&ui_info),
              0,
              &mut auth_package,
              None,
              0,
              &mut auth_buffer,
              &mut auth_buffer_size,
              Some(&mut save),
              CREDUIWIN_CHECKBOX,
          )
      };
  }
  ```

  If the credential provider was properly registered, the system will discover it and load the COM server into this process. Using `sxe ld cp_demo.dll` in WinDbg makes sure that we break into the debugger when the module gets loaded, allowing us to easily set breakpoints as desired.

### Dev experience

- *TBD:* Add a [build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) that

  - generates a GUID on each build
  - generate Rust source to be used for `CLSID_CP_DEMO`
  - generate register.reg and unregister.reg files with matching GUIDs

---

<sup>1</sup> *This one doesn't strictly implement functionality; its purpose initially was to act as a performance optimization, allowing the implementing module to get unloaded when it's no longer needed. A conforming implementation could simply return `S_FALSE` unconditionally, and opt out of this optimization, though for a credential provider it's probably wise to allow the system to unload it as soon as possible. Keeping an attack surface into high value information around for longer than necessary ain't no smart move.*

<sup>2</sup> *The actual interface methods do not need to be exported; they are returned to clients by way of arrays of function pointers.*

<sup>3</sup> *A full implementation will also require us to provide an implementation of [`ICredentialProviderCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nn-credentialprovider-icredentialprovidercredential), as that is returned from [`ICredentialProvider::GetCredentialAt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nf-credentialprovider-icredentialprovider-getcredentialat).*

Comment: Wow, I can't thank you enough already for the help. This is fantastic and I plan on implementing what I've learned here soon. 

Very much looking forward to those next TBD parts. Hope to hear from you soon :)

Comment: @IHaxYou The rabbit hole is deep. I'd implemented the interfaces of part `3.`, and know how `4.` would need to look like. The specific challenge now is to verify a few assumptions I'd glossed over, which comes down to observing how the compiled artifacts and a live system get along. So... setting up a sacrificial VM, finding a debugging strategy (that works, too), and a bit more research on top of that. Just to set expectations, that'll take a minute. I don't feel comfortable publishing `unsafe` Rust without thorough scrutiny.

Comment: God bless you sir. I'll buy you a steak dinner in thanks when all is said and done if you'd like. I eagerly await further updates. No rush lol.

Comment: Don't mean to rush you or anything, but are there any updates on this?

Comment: @IHaxYou Short update: I don't whether I'm making progress just yet. There's been a lot of back and forth trying to debug the system, with mixed results. I just started over with a new approach, that may allow me to exercise the credential provider infrastructure from a regular user-mode application. Which would mean no more fiddling with kernel debuggers. Still need to clean up enough disk space to be able to install all required tooling in the VM...

Comment: That's promising: The test application does indeed load the credential provider module, and calls into `DllGetClassObject`. Debug output shows up in the attached debugger, so everything is set for another all-nighter. Though I can't promise much, now that [gamozo](https://www.twitch.tv/gamozo) started streaming, out of nowhere...

Comment: lol alright, well thank you again for all your help. I'm not very knowledgeable about COM or Windows but If I can help at all just lmk. Wish you luck and hope to hear from you soon  :)

Comment: Still a fair bit missing, such as the DLL exports, notes on debugging, ideally a fully working implementation, plus the full test application. All of that seems to be rather straight forward, with just a lot of writing to get done (might get to this later today).

Comment: You absolute legend, thank you for all of your hard work. I'll save the rest of my thanks for that final update but I can't thank you enough for your work so far. Looking forward to that final update.

Comment: Hey, can't thank you enough for the work you've done so far, but is there any chance you might be able to include the debug information on how you managed to test the provider please?

Comment: @IHaxYou I've added the code for the test application. The text references information I haven't yet published (specifically the debugger setup). Feel free to hit me up when updates are a bit slow.

Comment: @IHaxYou I too have stumbled across the same project as you, do you have any open-source project I can use for reference?

Comment: @sn99, other than the C-projects I've referenced there isn't much available sadly. There is [another written in C#](https://github.com/SteveSyfuhs/CredProvider.NET) that could potentially be useful as another reference, but nothing in Rust that I know of. Hope that helps :)

Comment: @IInspectable Is there a project I could look at that has the complete sample?